# Cannot assign "40": "Group.groupParent_id" must be a "Group" instance

Tags: python, django

I want to add group from my group model. this one is recursive on parent-children relation.

But when I want to create a group with a children. I have the error

my model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    groupParent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
```

views.py:
My function which provoke error on line 18 GroupParent_id :

```
def add_group_fromcoa(request):  # add type and subtype of chart of account as first serie of group and subgroup

    # ------ Type adding -----
    types = ChartOfAccount.objects.order_by().values_list("field_type", flat=True).distinct()

    for type_types in types:

        upload_data = Group.objects.get_or_create(group_name=type_types,)

    types = ChartOfAccount.objects.order_by().values_list('field_subtype', flat=True).distinct()

    for type_types in types:
        looktype = ChartOfAccount.objects.filter(field_subtype=type_types).values('field_type').first()
        print("retour Groupe: {}".format(looktype['field_type']))
        looktyp= Group.objects.filter(group_name=looktype['field_type']).values('group_id').first()
        print("IDGroup: {}".format(int(looktyp['group_id'])))
        upload_data = Group.objects.get_or_create(
          group_name=type_types,
          groupParent_id=int(looktyp['group_id']))

    return redirect(home)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a foreign key relation in Django, Djano's default behavior is to name the column name `<object_column_name>_id`. So, when you add the field `groupParent_id`, Django names the database field `groupParent_id_id`. Now, when you have a foreign key on a Django model, you have two ways of referencing that relationship: you can use an object, or you can use a database primary key. If you use the name of the field from the model, the reference has to be an object. However, if you add `_id` onto the end, you can use the primary key, as you're trying to do here. If you change `groupParent_id=int(looktyp['group_id'])` to `groupParent_id_id=int(looktyp['group_id'])`, this should work.